# Mozilla Firefox not playing Flash video and reports error 2124

Tags: firefox, video, adobe-flash

I am trying to play videos given [here](http://www.learnerstv.com/Free-Computer-Science-Video-lectures-ltv163-Page1.htm) on my computer in my Mozilla Firefox browser on Windows 7 (64-bit). But it is giving me error 2124. Why is it so? However, I have successfully installed Adobe Flash Player for Firefox.

Comment: Are you using a proxy server?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682399/flash-proxy-error-2124

Comment: i have literally no idea whether this site uses it or not.

Comment: Try with chrome, it has a built-in flash.

Comment: Same problem with chrome .

Comment: What is your Firefox version? What is your Adobe Flash player version?

Comment: If it's not working in Firefox, and not in Chrome, then it has probably something to do with your network. This error code seems to be proxy related. Problems with authorities? My question was not if the site is using a proxy, but rather if you are using a proxy server to access it. Try from another computer, if that's an option. Other then that, you can try the usual drill, uninstall, reinstall Firefox, format and reinstall Windows, set things up again, or try booting form and using a Linux Live CD or USB.

Comment: Some software, or rather malware on your computer could be the culprit as well, blocking the video content for you. All those videos are posted on YouTube. So you could visit the author's channel and do a [query for python](http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston/search?query=python) and see if it works (he didn't make any useable playlists for the videos).

Answer (score 0):

This error code seems to be related to proxy settings. So check your proxy settings.

**Internet Explorer 11**

1. Tools (Gear button in upper right corner, Alt key, or Alt+X)
2. Internet Options
3. Connections
4. LAN Settings
5. Uncheck *Use a proxy server for your LAN* option in the Proxy server section.

**Firefox 30**

1. Menu (Menu button in upper right corner, or Alt key - Tools)
2. Options
3. Advanced
4. Network
5. Settings
6. Select "No proxy", "Auto-detet proxy for this network", or "Use
   system proxy settings".